# Changing the latex_engine gets an error when trying to align images on kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, xelatex

I am trying to copy the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555040/alignment-of-images-in-tables-with-markdown-rstudio-and-knitr) in this question.

The answer really meets what I wanted. But it get an error when the latex_engine is xelatex.

But I really needs to show the output in chinese.

Here's the code

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        latex_engine: xelatex
---

This example highlights the issue I am having with formatting a nice table with the graphics and the vertical alignment of text.

```{r echo=FALSE, results='hide', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
## Load modules
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

## Create a local function to plot the z score
varianceChart <- function(df, personNumber) {
  plot <- df %>%
             filter(n == personNumber) %>%
             ggplot() +
             aes(x=zscore, y=0) +
             geom_rect(aes(xmin=-3.32, xmax=-1.96, ymin=-1, ymax=1), fill="orange2", alpha=0.8) + 
             geom_rect(aes(xmin=1.96, xmax=3.32, ymin=-1, ymax=1), fill="olivedrab3", alpha=0.8) +
             geom_rect(aes(xmin=min(-4, zscore), xmax=-3.32, ymin=-1, ymax=1), fill="orangered3") + 
             geom_rect(aes(xmin=3.32, xmax=max(4, zscore), ymin=-1, ymax=1), fill="chartreuse4") +
             theme(axis.title = element_blank(), 
                   axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
                   axis.text = element_blank(),
                   panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                   panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
                   geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="black", alpha=0.3) +
                   geom_point(size=15, shape=4, fill="lightblue") ##Cross looks better than diamond
  return(plot)
}

## Create dummy data
Person1 <- rnorm(1, mean=10, sd=2) 
Person2 <- rnorm(1, mean=10, sd=2)
Person3 <- rnorm(1, mean=10, sd=2)
Person4 <- rnorm(1, mean=10, sd=2) 
Person5 <- rnorm(1, mean=10, sd=2) 
Person6 <- rnorm(1, mean=6,  sd=1) 

## Add to data frame
df <- data.frame(Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4, Person5, Person6)

## Bring all samples into one column and then calculate stats
df2  <- df %>% gather(key=Person, value=time)
mean <- mean(df2$time)
sd   <- sqrt(var(df2$time))

stats <- df2 %>%
             mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
             group_by(Person) %>%
             mutate(zscore = (time - mean) / sd)

graph_directory <- getwd() #'./Graphs'

## Now to cycle through each Person and create a graph
for(i in seq(1, nrow(stats))) {
  print(i)
  varianceChart(stats, i)

  ggsave(sprintf("%s/%s.png", graph_directory, i), plot=last_plot(), units="mm", width=100, height=20, dpi=1200)
}

## add a markup reference to this dataframe
stats$varianceChart <- sprintf('\\raisebox{-.4\\totalheight}{\\includegraphics[width=0.2\\textwidth, height=20mm]{%s/%s.png}}', graph_directory, stats$n) 

df.table <- stats[, c(1,2,5)]
colnames(df.table) <- c("Person Name", "Time taken", "Variance Chart")
```

```{r}
library(knitr)
kable(df.table[, c(1,2)], caption="Rows look neat and a sensible distance apart")
kable(df.table, caption="中文中文")
```
````

And it gives an error says

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.163 ...ers/knitr_try/1.png}}
                                                  \tabularnewline 

Try to find the following text in test.Rmd:
  ...ers/knitr_try/1.png}} 

You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r ` in test.Rmd (see the above hint). See https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385 for more info.
Error: LaTeX failed to compile test.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385) that says the error can be avoided,But I can't make any changes to this table. Am I missing something that can be changed?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error message. Instead, I get empty boxes for the Chinese characters, which isn't all that helpful either. I am pretty sure that the error message you got is not the root cause. I suspect the solution is to select a set of fonts that support the required characters. For example, I have the CJK variant for Noto installed, hence the following addition to the YAML header works for me:

```
mainfont: Noto Serif CJK TC
monofont: Noto Sans Mono CJK TC
sansfont: Noto Sans CJK TC
```

Result:

[image]

BTW, it is often helpful to follow the advice on https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging and set

```r
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

Comment: I remember reading that tinytex is a suggested choice by Yihui. I suggest installing tinytex.

Comment: But I have another question. I can't change the column width in this method.
The picture won't show up when I apply the "kableExtra" package, not to mention the column_spec function. I have also use the "linebreak" function, but it is still not working.

Comment: df.table$longletter=paste0(LETTERS,collapse = ","); library(kableExtra); kable(df.table,"latex") %>% kable_styling(full_width=F) %>% column_spec(4, width = "4em")

Comment: @蔡佳諭 This is difficult to judge based on the formatting imposed on comments. Can you post a new question instead?

Comment: @RalfStubner ok~ I will try to reproduce it.

Comment: @RalfStubner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60371743/is-it-possible-to-change-the-column-width-using-kable-without-kableextra
Thank you